# Using Bottle, need to create web-page

Tags: python, bottle

I'm relatively new with python. I'm creating a webpage and hosting it using heroku which supports bottle framework.
I need to create a website which takes data from a user and does some computation with it. For this i require text boxes and submit buttons. I know how to create these on simple forms using tkinter. How do i create these on a webpages.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. Have a go yourself and if you have a question about a specific problem you're encountering feel free to ask then.

Comment: People are not going to write code for you, but I would recommend using flask with heroku, there are lots of helpful resources on learning to make a website, with lots of plugins for flask as well.

Comment: Go look at the bottle documentation, then.

Comment: don't write code for me. Just tell me how to display buttons and text boxes on the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less of a Python question and more of an HTML question. You'll still need to write most of the page in HTML and then only 'deliver' the page to the user using Python, with [Bottlepy](http://www.bottlepy.com/docs/dev/tutorial.html#quickstart-hello-world), as you've mentioned .

You'll need to learn about HTML [Forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html) and [Inputs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-INPUT) to get anything done effectively. You'll also want to style the page with some CSS, which you can learn about from a variety of sources.

It sounds like you might also really benefit from some time spent on [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web), going through their tutorials on web development

Good luck!